# How can end-users "switch account" for connectors in a PowerApps Canvas App

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a canvas app that includes a few connectors (DevOps, BusinessCentral, MS Teams, PowerBI).

Once my users connect to the application initially, they get a dialog like this to provide permissions and switch accounts :
[image]

Once they have entered their information and gave the permission, they are redirected to the app. Everything is fine.

How can they proceed if they need to change the account they used initially to connect to the app? I tried everything (another browser, incognito session, cleared cookies, etc) it does not work, they are still logged in with the original credentials.

Where do the users have to go to change their connections authentication information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can navigate to the app details screen and then under the Connections tab, select the connection of choice and change the account from there.